# NewRelic sneaky reporting of exceptions with noticeNetworkFailure

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

We want to use NewRelic's *noticeNetworkFailure* behavior in Mobile to sneakily record exceptions in catch statements that aren't actually network exceptions; because this appears to be the only way for now to track exceptions with NewRelic Mobile.

The following example code doesn't appear to upload any event information, I pondered that it may be because NewRelic recognizes that the exception isn't a network exception and ignores the call.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
NewRelic.noticeNetworkFailure("HomeFragment.updateUi.IllegalStateException", time, time, new IllegalStateException());
```

The URL value is just a string we craft with *classname.method(or subclass then method).exceptionType* it allows identification of the related code and will theoretically group the exceptions under a common URL in NewRelic.

Has anyone done this before or knows what if anything I can do to achieve this?

**NB:** NewRelic is working perfectly in all other regards it's traces and other reporting is working well.

**Update #1:**
Still appears to be failing URL validation? I trigger a number of notices using the coding below and still get the Harvester sending 0 HTTP errors.

```
NewRelic.noticeNetworkFailure("http://exception.com/HomeFragment/updateUi/IllegalStateException", time, time+1, new IllegalStateException());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not going to work without further sneakiness.  Network errors aren't considered HTTP errors and will be grouped with HTTP transactions.  Instead, use NewRelic.noticeHttpTransaction like so:

```
NewRelic.noticeHttpTransaction("http://exception.com/HomeFragment/updateUi/IllegalStateException", 500, time, time+1, 0, 0);
```

If you add `http://exception/...` in front of the string, you'll pass the validation (although mind the characters in your string) and the error will show up on newrelic.com on the HTTP errors page.  Adding `exception` at the beginning will group these errors for easier reading.  However, be warned that you'll be mixing these errors up with 'real' ones generated by your app.

Always good to hear New Relic is working well for you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks asm this is exactly what I was after :D

Comment: Hmm it still appears to be failing the checking/validation, any ideas? I have added an update above.

Comment: Awesome @asm thank you, I had hoped to use noticeHttpFailure so that I could pass the exception for the stack trace, but I'm assuming that doesn't work as the exception is type checked for relevance? For now the noticeHttpTransaction will do perfectly, cheers :)

Comment: After reviewing the implementation in NewRelic I notice the stack track is provided by NewRelic when using noticeHttpTransaction, this is exactly what I wanted; thank you asm!